# '/usr/sbin' is not included in the PATH

Tags: root

```
blackj0221@NDELT-LAP-DELL:~$ su
Password:
root@NDELT-LAP-DELL:/home/blackj0221# su - blackj0221
Command 'service' is available in '/usr/sbin/service'
The command could not be located because '/usr/sbin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges associated with your user account.
service: command not found
blackj0221@NDELT-LAP-DELL:~$ echo $PATH
/home/blackj0221/bin:/home/blackj0221/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin
```

If I change my account from `root` to my ID, the error message **'/usr/sbin' is not included in the PATH** is displayed.

So I added `/usr/sbin` to the PATH but the error still comes out.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: It is not clear to me which service you are trying to access, but there is this: PATH does not provide privilege. In Ubuntu, the standard way to access admin privileges is to issue the command with sudo so ````$ sudo service <servicename> start````. However if you are using Ubuntu 16+, access service states through the systemctl command. So: ````sudo systemctl <action> <servicename> ```` This may predate 16. I forget when the change came.

Comment: Perhaps your `.bashrc` sets the `$PATH` _after_ calling `service ...`?

Comment: @StephenBoston I'm using `ssh` but I didn't try to access it. I just changed account and those error messages came out.

Comment: @PerlDuck There is no code associated with `$PATH` in `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Well `su - blackj0221` attempts to start a login shell for user blackj0221 - so check all the login shell related startup files (/etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile - assuming the user's login shell is `bash`)

Comment: Ah so you are on a remote host via ssh? And it is the ````su```` command that produces the error?! Try ````which su```` to see which executable is being called.  And you can try ````/bin/su```` which is the absolute path of su in the standard Ubuntu installation.

Comment: You wrote _"So I added `/usr/sbin` to the `PATH`"_. Where did you add it? I mean, which file did you edit?